# When can the compiler statically bind a call to a virtual function?

Tags: c++, performance, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, polymorphism

I expected the compiler to be able to statically resolve a function call to a virtual function if the type of the class is known at compile time (e.g. if the class instance is not being used through a reference or a pointer as illustrated in Case 1) below).

However, I have observed a strange behavior with Visual Studio 2010's C++ compiler and I would like to know if there is any reason for the compiler not to statically bind the calls to the "right" virtual function when the instances of the classes with the virtual functions are members in a structure that is being accessed by reference.

Should I expect the compiler to statically bind the calls to f() in Case 2) below? Is the "reference"ness of cr somehow propagating to cr.a even though `a` is an `A` and not an `A&`?

```
struct A
{
    virtual void f() ;
    virtual ~A() ;
};

struct B : A
{
    virtual void f() ;
    virtual ~B() ;
};

struct C {
    A a ;
    B b ;
};

C & GetACRef() ;

void test()
{
    // Case 1) The following calls to f() are statically bound i.e.
    // f() is called without looking up the virtual function ptr.
    C c ;  
    c.a.f() ;
    c.b.f() ;
    A a ;
    a.f() ;

    // Case 2) The following calls to f() go through the dynamic dispatching
    // virtual function lookup code. You can check if you generate the .asm
    // for this file.
    C & cr = GetACRef() ; // Note that C is not polymorphic
    cr.a.f() ; // visual C++ 2010 generates call to f using virtual dispatching
    cr.b.f() ; // visual C++ 2010 generates call to f using virtual dispatching  
}
```

Comment: Interestingly enough it seems that Clang does not optimize the virtual call either. Amusing. (It succeeds in optimizing `cr.b.f()` if I tag `B::f` as final)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why MSVC doesn't compile your "Case 2" scenarios to direct calls - it's certainly possible. I think that only Microsoft would be able to answer.

Note that GCC does perform the optimization that you're looking for (tested with MinGW 4.5.1 and `-O2`).

Also, MSVC used vtable dispatch even for the following sequence (for clarity - I'm using the `/Ox` optimization option):

```
A a;
A& ar(a);
ar.f();
```

So there's no need for a function or container struct to add layers of potential confusion to the compiler - there's no reason the compiler can't treat `ar.f()` exactly the same as `a.f()` in that sequence.  But as Bo Persson has suggested, perhaps it's not an extremely common optimization scenario (or MS have just plain not gotten around to it). Again, only the compiler devs at MS could answer.

I'm not sure I'd classify this behavior as 'strange' though - it's an optimization opportunity that's missed is all. I'm not sure how common this kind of thing might be.  Should you expect the compiler to generate statically bound calls in this case?  Maybe.  But I think it's not too surprising that it doesn't happen.

Maybe an issue should be opened on MS Connect.

Comment: your example is more complicated actually. In `cr.a.f()`, the type of `cr.a` is necessarily `A`, so the compiler knows the dynamic type with certainty. Knowing what `A&` is bound to requires control-flow analysis which is more expensive and trickier to implement.

Comment: Amusing, I tested with Clang 2.9, and in your case it successfully analyze that `A&` is bound to a `A` and devirtualize the call, though it still fails in the OP case. I'll try with a newer version, it certainly seems an easy enough case to optimize (at my high level :p)

Comment: @Matthieu: you're right that that requires is a different kind of analysis. I hadn't considered that. Note that GCC resolves `ar.f()` to a static call. Both of the scenarios are optimizations that I was under the impression that compilers commonly performed; however, I'm not entirely sure how important it might be in the real world.

Comment: It seems not as common :) I would not worry too much about it though, compilers have gone to length to optimize virtual calls wrt static calls and the overhead should not exceed 15% at most... so it's likely to be insignificant, unless the function is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously the compiler writers have not bothered to solve this case. Perhaps it is not common enough in real code to be worth their attention.

If `GetACRef` is defined elsewhere, it is also possible that C is polymorphic there, which could affect the optimizations.

Note that a compiler isn't solving every possible case where a small test program is "obvious" to a human. The compilers' focus is cases that happen often in large real programs.

Comment: What's an example of a definition of `GetACref` that could make this optimization invalid?

Comment: `GetACRef` could return a reference to `D` or `E` that is derived from `C` (in another module). If the compiler can't prove that this *never* affects the code, it can't do the optimizations.

Comment: Even if so, cr.a must refer to C::a, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: In this specific case, yes. In the general case, who knows?

Comment: How can cr.a not refer to the 'a' in C? If 'a' where a virtual function  I could see that it could go through some virtual dispatching but 'a' is just a member. Is there an example were .a could be something else? Thanks!

Comment: @Carlos - The compiler writers are trying to solve general cases, not specific test cases. Perhaps the "function returning a reference to an object with a member having a virtual function not used polymorphically" hasn't reached the top of their TODO-list yet?