# c++ overloading and overriding resolving time

Tags: c++, overriding

why overriding is resolved at runtime whereas overloading is resolved at compile time ?
is there any reason that overriding cant be resolved at compile time.

Comment: You tell us -- how _could_ overriding be resolved at compile time?

Comment: @ildjarn: You might want to check the link in comments under my answer.

Comment: @Als : Contexts where dynamic polymorphism is altogether _disabled_ (and thus irrelevant to the question/conversation) is not what I was asking about. Clearly one must be in a polymorphic context in order to use polymorphism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is there any reason that overriding cant be resolved at compile time.

Assuming you're talking about polymorphism, i.e.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Base::Foo()" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Derived::Foo()" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

The above code allows something like this to work as expected:

```
void CallFoo(Base& b)
{
    b.Foo(); 
}

int main()
{
    Base b;
    Derived d;
    CallFoo(b); // calls Base::Foo()
    CallFoo(d); // Calls Derived::Foo();
}
```

It is important to realize that `CallFoo()` knows nothing about what `b` actually is (it could be referring to a `Base` instance or to a `Derived` instance). All `CallFoo()` gets is a reference to `Base`, which tells nothing about what it actually refers to, so there's no way a compiler can tell what it is when it compiles `CallFoo()`.  Therefore, determining whether `Base::Foo()` or `Derived::Foo()` should be called is necessarily a runtime decision.

Removing the `virtual` keywords (to disable overriding) would cause the above code to print out `Base::Foo()` twice, not `Base::Foo()` then `Derived::Foo()`. This is because without the `virtual` keyword the compiler would simply resolve the call to `Base::Foo()` at compile time.

That being said, because virtual functions incur some overhead (after all, the right function that needs to be called is a runtime decision), compilers will try their best to figure out the actual type of `b` in `CallFoo()` if it can. In that case, it becomes a compile-time decision. It is, however, an implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

Overriding is only resolved at runtime for virtual functions, because that's how [dynamic binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch) is achieved.  Non-virtual function calls are resolved at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

**why overriding is resolved at runtime whereas overloading is resolved at compile time?**

It actually depends.
Usually, compilers cannot determine the actual function to be called untill runtime in case of overidding. This is because the actual object to which a Base class pointer maynot be known untill runtime. In such a case compilers have no option but to resolve the actual function call at run-time.
However, sometimes compilers can smartly & conclusively detect the function that needs to be called even in case of overidding and in such scenarios they can resolve the function to be called at compile time.

In case of Overloading the actual function to be called can be determined by the compilers based on just the parameters being passed to the function, so the compiler need not wait till run-time to resolve such calls because all parameter types are known at compile time, since C++ is a statically typed language all types have to be known at compile time.

Comment: `sometimes compilers can smartly & conclusively detect the function that needs to be called even in case of overidding` Do you have an example of this?

Comment: @Jesse: Check out: [When can the compiler statically bind a call to a virtual function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291596/when-can-the-compiler-statically-bind-a-call-to-a-virtual-function), And yes what i quoted is very much a proven fact.There is no guesswork here.

Answer (score 0):

Function overloading in C++ can be handled by the compiler itself. During function overloading, compiler "decorates" the function names, technically called `name mangling`. So in the generated code each overloaded method will have a separate name. This way compiler knows which method to call at compile time itself.

In the case of function overriding (a derived class redefines a method in its base class), if the base class method is non-virtual, then which function to call is determined at compile time itself. But if it is a virtual function, then compiler can't resolve the call at compile time. A virtual table look-up has to happen via the virtual pointer in the object. This can happen only at run-time, because only at run-time you will know which object you are dealing with.