# Are inheritance costs relative to whether objects are allocated on the stack or heap?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Consider the following setup.

```
class I
{
public:
    virtual void F() = 0;
};

class A : public I
{
public:
    void F() { /* some implementation */ }
};

class B : public I
{
public:
    void F() { /* some implementation */ }
};
```

This allows me to write a function like the following.

```
std::shared_ptr<I> make_I(bool x)
{
    if (x) return std::make_shared<A>();
    else return std::make_shared<B>();
}
```

In this situation, I am paying some costs for the inheritance and polymorphism, namely having a vtable and that calls to `F` can't be inlined when used like follows (correct me if I'm wrong).

```
auto i = make_I(false);
i->F(); //can't be inlined
```

What I want to know is if I have to pay these same costs when using `A` or `B` as objects allocated on the stack, like in the following code.

```
A a;
a.F();
```

Do `A` and `B` have vtables when allocated on the stack? Can the call to `F` be inlined?

It *seems* to me that a compiler could feasibly create two memory layouts for classes in an inheritance hierarchy - one for the stack and one for the heap. Is this what a C++ compiler will/may do? Or is there a theoretical or practical reason it can't?

---

Edit:

I saw a comment (that looks like it was deleted) that actually raised a good point. You could always do the following, and then that `A a` was allocated on the stack might not be the salient point I'm trying to get at...

```
A a;
A* p = &a;
p->F(); //likely won't be inlined (correct me if I'm wrong)
```

Maybe a better way to phrase it would be "Is the behavior different for an object that is allocated on the stack *and is used as a 'regular value type'*?" Please help me out here with the terminology if you know what I mean but have a better way of putting it!

The point I'm trying to get at is that you could feasibly, at compile time, "flatten" the definition of the base class into the derived class you are allocating an instance of on the stack.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When can the compiler statically bind a call to a virtual function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7291596/420683)

Comment: @DyP That definitely looks related - thanks, I'm going to read through it all. But I'm not sure if it's duplicate. The distinction is that here I'm also interested in whether the compiler can vary things like the memory layout (and size) of a type based on usage.

Comment: @TimothyShields The size and layout of a class are always the same.

Comment: @brianbeuning Yeah, you're right - how would `sizeof(A)` work if that weren't true? I think Scott Jones' answer got to the bottom of what I was really after.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your question really has to do with whether a compiler has static knowledge of an object and can elide the vtable lookup (you mentioned this in your edit), rather than whether there is a distinction on where the object lives - stack or heap.  Yes, many compilers can elide the virtual dispatch in that case.

Comment: Just wanted to add that the objects will always have vtables whether they're used or not, unless the class is so simple and its lifetime so short that the compiler can elide the object completely.

Comment: Having looked back at the real application I was researching this for and then reviewed your answer, I think you're right - it's really just eliding the vtable lookup that I'm actually interested in.

Answer (score 1):

The edit to your question asks whether you can flatten the definition of the base class, `A`, into the derived class, `B`.  If the compiler can tell, at compile time, that an object will only ever contain an instance of `B` then it can eliminate the vtable lookup at runtime and call `B.F();` for that particular call.

For example, the compiler will *probably* eliminate the vtable lookup at runtime below and call the derived function:

```
B b;
b.F();
```

In the code below, the compiler will not be able to eliminate the runtime lookup in `doSomething`, but it *probably* can eliminate the lookup in `b.F()`

```
void doSomething( A* object ) {
    object->F();   // will involve a vtable lookup
}

B b;
b.F();    // probably won't need a vtable lookup
doSomething( &b );
```

Note it does not matter whether object is allocated on the stack or the heap.  What matters is that the compiler is able to determine the type.  Each class will still have a vtable, it just might not always be needed for each method call.

You mention code inlining, this is not related to how the object is allocated.  When a normal function is called, variables will be pushed onto the stack along with a return address.  The CPU will then jump to the function.  With inline code, the site of the function call is replaced with the actual code (similar to a macro).

If an object contained in an inheritance hierarchy is allocated on the stack, the compiler still needs to be able to determine what functions it can call, especially if there are virtual and non-virtual functions.

Comment: Suppose I have `class A { ... }` and `class B : public A { ... }`, and then I have code `B b; /* anything using b */`. It seems like I can always defined a `class B2` that is equivalent to `B` if it's restricted to only being used in 'non-polymorphic' ways, regardless of what's in the definition of `A` or `B`...at least theoretically...  Maybe I'm being naive about it though. A counterexample of why that statement can't be the case in general would pretty much convince me because I'm already skeptical that it's possible. It's just something I'm curious about.